# django fail to create project

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I want to use the DjangoCMS 3.3 version to create a new project.
I use the following guide http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/install.html

but when running the the command

```
djangocms -f -p . mysite
```

i get the error 
"'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The installation Failed"

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the problem that `djangocms` cannot recognize the path with spaces. Change your project path without any space.

Comment: Actually, the path is "C:\Users\User\Documents\test". Could it be ralated with the installation path? such as "Program Files"

Comment: Well, try to reinstall your `djangocms` into another path with no space. In most case, such error always happen if a program cannot handle the path with spaces correctly. The almost only solution is try to avoid using such a path.